# using Linux wget tag to grab website

Tags: linux, wget

there is some site - www.elections.am/votersreg
and I want to know how can i grab the whole information in this website using linux wget tag?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's an odd way of referring to a "command"?

Comment: If you want to do some cool stuff use perl and the embeded LWP::Simple you can load the site, if you require more intelligence perl contains also some www libraries to enter content and submit it. http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/Simple.pm

Answer (score 1):

you can use `wget -r` or install a program called "httrack" and use that to mirror the url to a folder

Answer (score 0):

Another answer suggested 'wget -r' which may work for you.  However, in order to best "grab the whole information in this website" as your question states, I think 'wget --mirror' and maybe 'wget --mirror --convert-links' would be stronger solutions.  The -r option defaults to 5 levels of recursion, where --mirror gives infinite levels of recursion.  The --convert-links option will convert the links within the downloaded documents as appropriate to make them suitable for local browsing, if that is your goal.

I would be careful with the 'infinite recursion' aspect here.  That can get out of hand so you may want to monitor the download progress.  You can also explicitly define the depth of recursion with the --level=depth option.